# Oracle: Joining on TOP 1 record

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've seen a few answers on here to similar questions but haven't quite been able to implement this correctly.

I want to create a JOIN between 2 oracle tables that should create a 1-to-1 relationship.  Unfortunately, due to the setup of my 2nd table, it returns a 1-to-many relationship.

So here's my 2 tables.  "Items" contains the item name & the item's lot #.  I then need to reach into our "Item_Inventory" table to find whether the item is currently in stock (if the item is not currently in this table, it's not in stock).

```
===========================
ITEMS
===========================
Item_No     |   Lot_Num
---------------------------
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z
ALC-6697-MI |   A237520P
---------------------------

=======================================================
ITEM_INVENTORY
=======================================================
Item_No     |   Lot_Num    |  BIN_LOC  |  QTY_ONHAND 
-------------------------------------------------------
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R   |   P8541E  |     82      
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R   |   Q8870Q  |     82      
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R   |   U4142B  |     82      
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z   |   P5888D  |     15
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z   |   R5588Z  |     15
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z   |   W8339A  |     15
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT i.Item_No, i.Lot_Num 
FROM ITEMS i
JOIN ITEM_INVENTORY inv ON inv.Item_No = i.Item_No AND inv.Lot_Num = i.Lot_Num
```

Here's what I want to return (notice the item "ALC-6697-MI" is excluded because it has no current stock in the Item_Inventory table):

```
Item_No     |   Lot_Num
---------------------------
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z
```

Instead, because of the Item_Inventory.Bin_Loc field, I'm getting this when I JOIN:

```
Item_No     |   Lot_Num    
-------------------------
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R     
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R      
SHP-705-F   |   X456588R      
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z  
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z  
BAG-DRAWSTR |   Y245899Z
```

How can I JOIN these 2 tables but keep it as a 1 to 1 relationship?

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE show your query.

Comment: Sorry, updated to include my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: Just add distinct to your select clause:

```
select distinct ITEMS.Item_No, ITEMS.Lot_Num
from ... /* the rest of your query*/
```

Option 2: Use exists clause:

```
select i.Item_No, i.Lot_Num
from ITEMS i
where exists (
    select *
    from ITEM_INVENTORY inv
    where inv.Item_no = i.Item_no and inv.Lot_Num = i.Lot_Num
)
```

Comment: Nice one on the EXISTS query; I should've spotted that myself! *{;-) Also, I pushed the distinct down into the subquery to reduce the amount of rows being joined. It might not make a difference in this case, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Yeah. There's not really a big improvement on moving the distinct to the subquery. Once the first tuple that satisfies the exists clause is found, the DBMS doesn't need to keep checking the remaining tuples. ;-)

Comment: Using the distinct operator in a exists clause is unnecessary and may even be detrimental to the queries performance.  BTW @Jodevan you should probably include the `and inv.lot_num = i.lot_num` predicate in your subqueries where clause. as @Boneist and I did in our responses unless the OP is unconcerned about the lot numbers when checking for inventory.

Comment: As Sentinel implied, I wasn't suggesting using DISTINCT in the exists query, but rather in your first query. Reading my comment back, that wasn't very obvious, sorry!

Comment: @Sentinel You're right. I haven't included it though due to the data he's presented. According to his data, the tables don't seem normalized and there is redundancy. Actually, according to the question, we wouldn't even have to query items, a simple `select distinct Item_No, Lot_Num from item_inventory` would return the desired data :D. Anyways, I'll update my query. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  The exists clause worked for what I needed.

Comment: @Jodevan your simple select is an excellent solution to the stated problem, unless the OP needs some data in the ITEMS table not mentioned in the problem statement.  You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an in clause:

```
select i.Item_No, i.Lot_Num
  from ITEMS i
 where (i.Item_No, i.Lot_Num)
    in (select inv.Item_No, inv.Lot_Num
          from ITEM_INVENTORY inv
         where inv.Item_no = i.Item_no
           and inv.Lot_Num = i.Lot_Num)
```

The sub query above can be either correlated (as shown) or uncorrelated by leaving off the `where inv.Item_no = i.Item_no and inv.Lot_Num = i.Lot_Num` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest and (probably, but you'd have to test on your data) quickest to just do a distinct before joining the two tables, eg. something like:

```
select *
from   items i
       inner join (select distinct item_no, lot_num from item_inventory) ii on (ii.item_no = i.item_no and ii.lot_num = i.lot_num);
```

You could also assign a number to each row in the group of items in the inventory table, but that might take longer. You'd have to test, of course! E.g.

```
select *
from   items i
       inner join (select item_no, lot_num, row_number() over (partition by item_no, lot_num order by bin_loc) rn from item_inventory) ii on (ii.item_no = i.item_no and ii.lot_num = i.lot_num and ii.rn = 1);
```